# Submit form with <a>

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have :

```
<ul>
  <form name="myform" action="Users" id="myform" method="post">
    <li><a id="target" name="target" value='A' href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a id="target" name="target" value='B' href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a id="target" name="target" value='C' href="#">C</a></li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

And in my controller I want to retrieve the value like this `Request.Form["target"]`.

How can I, with a `<a>` send my form with the `<a>` value inside it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all,

I did a mix from some solutions :

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="submit('A');">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="submit('B');">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="submit('C');">C</a></li>
  <input name="target" type="hidden" value=""/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function submit(target) {
        document.forms['myform'].elements['target'].value = target;
        document.myform.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only form elements (select, input, textarea) are submitted to server. And value is not a valid attribute of `a` tag. If the only thing you need is to get value of clicked link - you can use href:

```
<li><a id="target" name="target" href="?target=A">A</a></li>
<li><a id="target" name="target" href="?target=B">B</a></li>
<li><a id="target" name="target" href="?target=C">C</a></li>
```

And than on server:

```
Request["target"]
```

Otherwise - you need to do onclick handler for `a` and there take a value of clicked `a`, put it into some hidden field and than call `document.myform.submit()`;

Answer (score 1):

First of all, having more than one element with same id is invalid HTML - don't do that. Having the same `name` is valid, so keep it.

Second, you'll have to use JavaScript to populate hidden form input and auto submit the form. Add the hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="target" />
```

Then have such code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var oForm = document.forms["myform"];
    var oHiddenInput = oForm.elements["target"];
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        if (anchors[i].name === "target") {
            anchors[i].onclick = function() {
                oHiddenInput.value = this.value;
                oForm.submit();
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try this:

```
<ul>
  <form name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="target"  id="target" value="">
    <li><a class="target" id="t1" name="target" rel='A' href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a class="target" id="t2" name="target" rel='B' href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a class="target" id="t3" name="target" rel='C' href="#">C</a></li>
  </form>
</ul>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.target').click(function(){
           $('#target').val($(this).attr('rel'));
           $('#myform').submit();

        });
     });
</script>
```